# Does tangent exist at $x=1$ to $y(x) =\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}x\right)-\sqrt{1-x^2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

$y(x) =\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}x\right)-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is defined on $(0,1]$. Does there exist it's tangent at the end point $x=1$ ?

Left hand derivative of $y(x)$ exists at the point at $x=1$ and it is continuous on $(0,1]$.

But I can not understand if tangent to $y(x)$ at $x=1$ exists.I think any straight line which passes through $(1,0)$ will be a tangent to $x=1$ to $y(x)$ because it just touches at that point.

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: How are you defining a tangent?

Comment: Find here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent @askingquestions

Comment: Compute $\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}$ by putting $ x=y+1$

Comment: I know it exists. Please have a look at my question.  Value of this limit will be zero.@hamam_Abdallah

Comment: I know what a tangent is:) I wanted to know if you knew, since if you work with a proper definition the answer will be obvious. How are *you* defining tangent?

Comment: Tangent line to a plane curve at a given point is the straight line that "just touches" the curve at that point.@askingquestions

Comment: @anonymous Now you have to define what “just touches” mean. Beware not to go into a vicious circle.

Answer (score 0):

For $\theta\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$

$$y(\sin\theta)=\ln\left(\frac{1+\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}\right)-\cos\theta=-\ln\tan\frac{\theta}{2}-\cos\theta $$
hence
$$ (\cos\theta)\cdot y'(\sin\theta) = -\frac{1}{\sin\theta}+\sin\theta=-\frac{\cos^2\theta}{\sin\theta} $$
and
$$ y'(\sin\theta) = -\cot\theta, $$
$$ y'(x) = -\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}.$$
This simply gives that $\lim_{x\to 1^-}y'(x)=0$.

Comment: Can you please have a look at my question ? I know how to find the left hand derivative at this point. I am asking if tangent exists at this point .@Jack D'Aurizio

Comment: What is your definition of *tangent*? $y(x)$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$ , continuous on $(0,1]$ and the left derivative at $x=1$ is finite, so there is a tangent.

Comment: Tangent at a point $x=c$ to the function $f(x)$ is nothing but the best linear approximation near the point $c$.@Jack D'Aurizio

Comment: "Best" in which sense?

Comment: Suppose slope of the best linear approximation is $m$. For anyother line we will get a positive number $\epsilon$ such that for every $\delta>0$, there is $x_0 \in (c-\delta , c+\delta)  $ such that any secant passing through $(c,f(c))$ and $(x_0,f(x_0))$ has slope not belonging to $(m-\epsilon , m+\epsilon)$.@Jack D'Aurizio

Comment: The slope of the optimal line is the derivative at such point, so you are just stating that "having tangents" means "being differentiable"

Comment: We can find the best linear approximation when one side of the derivative exists. My question is if we can say tangent exists when function itself is not defined on the other side like here. $f(x)$ is not defined on $(1, \infty)$.@Jack D'Aurizio

Comment: Yes, of course, there are left tangents as well as left derivatives.